# How to transition Views programmatically using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to show the user another view when the login is successful, otherwise stay on that view. I've done that with UIKit by performing a segue. Is there such an alternative in SwiftUI?

The NavigationButton solution does not work as I need to validate the user input before transitioning to the other view.

```swift
Button(action: {
    let authService = AuthorizationService()
    let result = authService.isAuthorized(username: self.username, password: self.password)
    if(result == true) {
        print("Login successful.")
        // TODO: ADD LOGIC
        *** HERE I WANT TO PERFORM THE SEGUE ***

        presentation(MainView)
    } else {
        print("Login failed.")
    }
}) {
    Text("Login")
}
```

Comment: I have posted an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61068416/2857130) that conveniently uses `NavigationView` and `NavigationLink`.

Comment: Checkout SwiftUI navigation library github.com/canopas/UIPilot for easy navigation.

Answer (score 4):

Xcode 11 beta 5.

`NavigationDestinationLink` and `NavigationButton` have been deprecated and replaced by `NavigationLink`.

Here's a full working example of programatically pushing a view to a NavigationView.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine


enum MyAppPage {
    case Menu
    case SecondPage
}

final class MyAppEnvironmentData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentPage : MyAppPage? = .Menu
}

struct NavigationTest: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            PageOne()
        }
    }
}


struct PageOne: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var env : MyAppEnvironmentData


    var body: some View {
        let navlink = NavigationLink(destination: PageTwo(),
                       tag: .SecondPage,
                       selection: $env.currentPage,
                       label: { EmptyView() })

        return VStack {
            Text("Page One").font(.largeTitle).padding()

            navlink
            .frame(width:0, height:0)

            Button("Button") {
                self.env.currentPage = .SecondPage
            }
            .padding()
            .border(Color.primary)

        }
    }

}


struct PageTwo: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var env : MyAppEnvironmentData

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Page Two").font(.largeTitle).padding()

            Text("Go Back")
            .padding()
            .border(Color.primary)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.env.currentPage = .Menu
            }
        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct NavigationTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationTest().environmentObject(MyAppEnvironmentData())
    }
}
#endif
```

Note that the `NavigationLink` entity has to be present inside the View body.
If you have a button that triggers the link, you'll use the label of the NavigationLink.
In this case, the NavigationLink is hidden by setting its frame to 0,0, which is kind of a hack but I'm not aware of a better method at this point. .hidden() doesn't have the same effect.

Comment: Sorry, did you mention that you need to change this line on SceneDelegate.swift for this to work. let contentView = NavigationTest().environmentObject(MyAppEnvironmentData()) FYI

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like bellow, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56978678/554203) response (it's packed like a Playground for easy testing:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import PlaygroundSupport


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MainView().navigationBarTitle(Text("Main View"))
        }
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    let afterLoginView = DynamicNavigationDestinationLink(id: \String.self) { message in
        AfterLoginView(msg: message)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print("Do the login logic here")
            self.afterLoginView.presentedData?.value = "Login successful"
        }) {
            Text("Login")
        }
    }
}

struct AfterLoginView: View {
    let msg: String

    var body: some View {
        Text(msg)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
```

---

Although this will work, I think that, from an architectural perspective, you try to push an "imperative programming" paradigm into SwiftUI's reactive logic. 
I mean, I would rather implement it with the login logic wrapped into an `ObjectBinding` class with an exposed `isLoggedin` property and make the UI react to the current state (represented by `isLoggedin`).

Here's a very high level example :

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    @ObjectBinding private var loginManager = LoginManager()

    var body: some View {
        if loginManager.isLoggedin {
            Text("After login content")
        } else {
            Button(action: {  
                 self.loginManager.login()
            }) {
                 Text("Login")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a Bool state for my login transition, it seems pretty fluid.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var loggedIn = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if self.loggedIn {
                Text("LoggedIn")
                Button(action: {
                    self.loggedIn = false 

                }) {
                    Text("Log out")
                }
            } else {
                LoginPage(loggedIn: $loggedIn)
            }
        }
    }
}
```