# SWIFTUI button login authentication and go to new View

Tags: swift, button, swiftui

I ned easy validation TextField after enter Email and password, next step push button, check Email and Password and go to next View. How it make? I have a some code State var and Button:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var email = "1"
    @State var password = "1"

    Button(action: {
              if self.email == "1" && self.password == "1"{
              print("Button tapped")
              NextMyView()
              }else {
           print("error")
                            }
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                        }
```

But my idea dos not work, how I can make this validation and after push button go to next View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need [`NavigationView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink) and a [`NavigationLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink) to achieve what you're looking for.

`NavigationView` will wrap all the inner views within a navigation controller, and `NavigationLink` is like a special button that triggers the navigation.

#### Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var email: String = "root"
  @State private var password: String = "toor"
  
  @State private var isLoginValid: Bool = false
  @State private var shouldShowLoginAlert: Bool = false
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack(alignment: .center) {
        TextField("email", text: self.$email)
        TextField("password", text: self.$password)
        
        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Success"),
                       isActive: self.$isLoginValid) {
                /*
                 Here we put the content view of `NavigationLink`.
                 It could be any `View` even `Button` but in this
                 example we use a `Text` with `onTapGesture`.
                 */
                Text("Login")
                    .onTapGesture {
                    //determine login validity
                    let isLoginValid = self.email == "root" && self.password == "toor"
                    
                    //trigger logic
                    if isLoginValid {
                      self.isLoginValid = true //trigger NavigationLink
                    }
                    else {
                      self.shouldShowLoginAlert = true //trigger Alert
                    }
                }
        }
      }
      .navigationBarTitle("Login Screen")
      .alert(isPresented: $shouldShowLoginAlert) {
        Alert(title: Text("Email/Password incorrect"))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`NavigationLink` defines:

1. `destination` which navigates to a simple `Text` view

   - In your case you should change it to `NextMyView()`
2. `isActive` binded to a boolean value `loginSuccess` which when updated to `true` shall re-render the view and cause `NavigationLink` to fire automatically
3. The content view is a simple `Text` with a `onTapGesture` in which we can implement the success/failure case handling.

   - In your case, you could change `Text` to `Image(systemName: "heart.fill")`

PS: As an extra, I included the logic to trigger and show an alert on login failure.
Hope it helps :)